# How do I get my program to update this tkinter label in my nested loop so that it shows the grayscale process?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, python-imaging-library

So I made a program that converts an image to grayscale. I first used graphics.py from a Zelle's Python Programming An Introduction To Computer Science book. I believe this is based on tkinter. I finished the program using a nested loop to iterate through a .gif picture and grab each individual pixel, replacing it with a grayscale algorithm. I had the change happen in a loop and it gave it an effect that shows the grayscale happening across the window. This was slow but it looked neat, but I realized I wanted to be able to use more file types. I found PIL for Python 3.3 and tkinter, using PIL to open the images, turning them into a tkinter PhotoImage, than displaying them in a tkinter window. Now my program will show the image before being processed and after, I would simply like to see the program update the image in the loop so that it shows the grayscale process. Any help would be great appreciated.

Here is my code:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
from graphics import GraphWin
import tkinter

window = tkinter.Tk()
window.title('# Grayscale')

def GrayScaleConvertor():

    #Opens image, creates window and draws image
    picToConvert = 'sea.jpg'
    pic = Image.open(picToConvert)

    picWidth, picHeight = pic.size


    # Treats the image as a 2d array, iterates through changing the
    #values of each pixel with the algorithm for gray
    tkPic = ImageTk.PhotoImage(pic, master = window)
    label1 = tkinter.Label(window, image = tkPic)

    rgbList = pic.load() #Get a 2d array of the pixels
    for row in range(picWidth):
        for column in range(picHeight):
            rgb = rgbList[row,column]
            r,g,b = rgb # Unpacks the RGB value tuple per pixel
            grayAlgorithm1 = (r+g+b) // 3
            rgbList[row,column] = (grayAlgorithm1, grayAlgorithm1, grayAlgorithm1)

        # Converting to a tkinter PhotoImage
    tkPic1 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(pic, master = window)
    label2 = tkinter.Label(window, image = tkPic1)

    # Draws the images to the window
    label1.pack() # The image before grayscale
    label2.pack() # The image after being grayscaled
    window.mainloop()

GrayScaleConvertor()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `after(time, function_name)` to call function (for example) every 10ms and change one (or more) pixel.

pseudocode:

```
tkinter.after(10, change_one_pixel)

def change_one_pixel():
     change_next_pixel() # if you change more pixels you get faster animation
     create_new_image()
     update_label()
     if any_pixel_left:
        tkinter.after(10, change_one_pixel)
```

**EDIT:**

Full working code

```
#import Tkinter as tk # Python 2.7.x
import tkinter as tk # Python 3.x

from PIL import Image, ImageTk

class GrayScaleConvertor():

    def __init__(self):

        self.window = tk.Tk()
        self.window.title('# Grayscale')

        #Opens image, creates window and draws image
        picToConvert = 'sea.jpg'
        #picToConvert = 'background.jpg'
        self.pic = Image.open(picToConvert)

        # Treats the image as a 2d array, iterates through changing the
        #values of each pixel with the algorithm for gray
        self.tkPic1 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.pic, master = self.window)
        self.label1 = tk.Label(self.window, image = self.tkPic1)

        # Converting to a tkinter PhotoImage
        self.tkPic2 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.pic, master = self.window)
        self.label2 = tk.Label(self.window, image = self.tkPic2)

        # Draws the images to the window
        self.label1.pack() # The image before grayscale
        self.label2.pack() # The image after being grayscaled

        self.column = 0 # start column
        self.step = 10 # number columns in one step
        self.window.after(1, self.change_pixel) # 1ms

    def run(self):
        self.window.mainloop()

    def change_pixel(self):

        rgbList = self.pic.load() #Get a 2d array of the pixels
        picWidth, picHeight = self.pic.size

        # not to leave image
        if self.column + self.step > picWidth:
            self.step = picWidth - self.column

        # change columns
        for column in range(self.column, self.column+self.step):
            for row in range(picHeight):
                rgb = rgbList[column,row]
                r,g,b = rgb # Unpacks the RGB value tuple per pixel
                grayAlgorithm1 = (r+g+b) // 3
                rgbList[column,row] = (grayAlgorithm1, grayAlgorithm1, grayAlgorithm1)

        # change image in label
        if self.tkPic2:
            del self.tkPic2
        self.tkPic2 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.pic, master = self.window)
        self.label2.config(image = self.tkPic2)

        # move start column
        self.column += self.step

        # if still are columns - call again
        if self.column < picWidth:
            print "change image"
            self.window.after(1, self.change_pixel)
        else:
            print "the end"

GrayScaleConvertor().run()
```

Comment: Specifically with Tkinter, I can't update the Label with a new image after creating it. Thanks for the after method, I will use this instead of the time module.

Comment: You can change `Label` image using `label2.config(image=new_image)`. Or you can remove `Label` using `label2.pack_forget()` and create new `Label`. You can use `config()` and `pack_forget()` for all widgets.

Comment: This doesn't work in the loop, I've tried a few different ways, It just doesn't seem like tkinter will run the code for every iteration of every pixel.

Comment: See full working code in my answer. I think it could be done without `class` but With `class` it looks much cleaner for me.